# Python KeyError with configparser?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module, config, keyerror

I need your help after I tried everything in my hands with no luck.

Please Note: My code runs perfect on macOS, the problem discussed is regarding Windows OS.

I have the following line in python:

```
if int(major) < int(config['NMAP']['MIN_MAJOR']) or (
```

where:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini')
```

and the contents of the config file are:

```
[NMAP]
MIN_MAJOR = 7
MIN_MINOR = 92

[FING]
```

When I run my file I get:

```
File "C:\Users\dc\src\network_scanner\nmap_scanner.py", line 15, in __init__
    if int(major) < int(config['NMAP']['MIN_MAJOR']) or (
  File "C:\Users\usr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\configparser.py", line 964, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'NMAP'
```

Comment: Are you certain you're using the same ```config.ini```?  Given your code and the config.ini you provided, I got a value of 7.

Comment: @ewong yes I'm 100% sure, on macos it's 100%, it's not working on ubuntu or windows...

Comment: What happens if you do a ```print(config.sections())``` before the ```if int(major)...``` line?